# How to row bind two data frames in SparkR

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

In R we use rbind() to bind two data frames eg.) rbind(X , Y) 
How can we do the same in SparkR in spark 1.4

TIA, 
Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unionAll(X,Y)
```

Check out the API docs at:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html